# Is Zephirine Drouhin rose completely thornless?

Tags: roses

An advertisement of Zephirine Drouhin rose said that this rose was disease resistant, shade tolerant, alkaline soil tolerant, pollution tolerant, more floriferous than other varieties, and completely thornless. I suppose they are probably being optimistic about it: I would especially like to know about the thornlessness. Are these really completely thornless?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a Zephirine Drouhin Rose that has been growing in USDA zone 4 for two years.  It puts on a great show, grows fast, resistant to powdery mildew but **it is not thornless**.

Compared to the shrub roses I have you can work with it without gloves.  There are not many thorns, perhaps one every inch on the larger stems only.  The thorns are a 1/4" in length and as picky as you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

The Bourbon rose is also known as 'The Thornless Rose'.

> This is one of the classic roses, introduced in 1868 and cherished for
>   generations for its lavish and unsophisticated flower display, and its
>   ease of cultivation, **not least the thornless stems which make pruning
>   a pleasure**.

Source: [BBC Gardening](http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/plants/plant_finder/plant_pages/783.shtml)

[davesgarden.com](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/354) mentions 'Stems are nearly thornless'

Answer (score 3):

I grow this beautiful rose, so from personal experience I can tell you that mine is completely thorn less! (I wish all the roses were like this) It grows on one end of a pergola in my rose garden.  You can learn more about this rose here: http://www.allaboutrosegardening.com/Zephirine-Drouhin-Rose.html

Comment: Thanks, that is good to hear! I'm interested in how many consecutive hours of direct sun yours gets.